# Why put a View under ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I see several tutorial of UIScrollView put a View component under UIScrollView component, something like below:

[image]

In the example above, the "Content View" is a View component which is made the same size as "Scroll View". Buttons are put on "Content View"

I am wondering what are the benefits of doing this? Why not directly put those buttons on Scroll View? What is the purpose/benefits of having Scroll View host a "Content View" & put buttons on "Content View"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people find it easier to maintain that way.

For example:

I have a scroll view, with 10 subviews... The "first" subview defines the top-left of the `.contentSize` and the "tenth" subview defines the bottom-right of the `.contentSize`. I add an 11th subview, and I have to change various constraints to re-define the content.

Or...

I have a scroll view with ONE subview - the "Content View". In that content view, I have 10 subviews. I can add / remove subviews from that content view, and the scrollview's `.contentSize` remains controlled by *only* the constraints on the "Content View".

Personally, I prefer adding views directly to the scroll view. Although, frequently, using a `UIStackView` as the "content view" works like a charm.